# Google App Engine unexpected 'site can't provide a secure connection' error

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

Three days ago, I was able to access my website deployed onto Google App Engine with no issues. Since that time I haven't changed anything in the files for my project, but when I deployed recently I was given a `site can't provide a secure connection` error, and the website was `sent an invalid response`.

I'm not sure whether this is an issue on App Engine or my code, as this only occurs with the most recently deployed instance of the website on App Engine. For example, I have deployed once, been given this error, then deployed again a couple minutes later, and that initial instance that is now second in line (with 0% traffic) works fine, while the new most recent (active) instance with 100% traffic, has the same error.

[image]

I am working with a Flask framework with the correct file structure, including static & templates folders, app.yaml and main.py files. I'm happy to post specific code snippets as requested in comments, I just don't know what code would be helpful to diagnose since there haven't been any changes since it was working fine a couple days ago with the same code.

Any ideas and advice is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Removing the 's' from https takes me to the following page... clicking 'proceed anyway' takes me to the website just fine though

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things to try to diagnose:

1. Check for errors locally, on your dev server.  May have a 5xx error in your new code.
2. Navigate to http(without the 's')://your-app-and-version.appspot.com to see if that loads.

Comment: I just tried removing the 's' - have added the results in an edit on the original post. Looking into local errors on the dev server now

Comment: The site loads fine here in the US.  Your ISP is what is blocking it.  They are sensing some suspicious code.  Hopefully, your local server sheds some light.

Comment: This is very confusing... it works fine now! Must have been when I clicked proceed anyway from safebrowse. I will still check under the developer tools on chrome for anything unusual, since all my deployments are launched online and not on a local server. But it seems that it solved itself with such a minor solution. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'll also look into figuring out how to make sure this doesn't happen again, especially for visitors to the site. Most likely looking into certificates and security to make sure the site isn't deemed 'suspicious'